# How to use verb with did

Tags: verbs, questions, auxiliary-verbs

I have a question on using verb.

> - Did you call me yesterday?
> - Did you called me yesterday?

Which one is correct? *Did* says the incident happened in past so I don't know if I can use *called*. Please advice.

Comment: You may find [ell.se] more suitable for this type of basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since *did* already indicates the past tense, we do not say 'called'. Your first sentence is correct.

And the verb form of advice is spelt with an **s**.

> Please *advise* me.

On reading that, I gave you some *advice*.

Answer (score 0):

in questions and negatives use **did/didn't** + *infinitive* (**enjoy/call/see** etc.)

Q :Did you go out last night ? A : Yes, I went to the cinema but I didn't enjoy the film much.

I suggest [English Grammar in Use](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052118939X) to improve your grammar issues.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb: contrary to practice in other languages, in English **the past is marked only once**.